# Firebase Real-time database with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I'm searching 3 days now for a tutorial in firebase real time database and not firestore and i can't find anything.

I just want to retrieve some data from my db and then display it on a list

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: See Help Center to find out what types of questions are acceptable here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the new Firebase Quickstart for Real Time Database at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/database/DatabaseExampleSwiftUI/DatabaseExample. It's still in progress, but should be enough to get you started.